# Dynamic generation of UI from Json

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to dynamically build UI from the json.

Can someone please point me in the right direction or give me some suggestions?

Comment: You should ask a more specific question. What have you tried? What problems did you find?

Comment: I have a json which contents uielements with some properties like farme etc.Now i am trying to create a class where in if you pass the json object,it should return an object(uilement) like uilabel,unbutton etc.FYI,I don't want to return an uiview ,i want to return an nsobject which from again user should be able to know what type of object is that like uilabel or unbutton etc. can you help me out ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can parse easily a json to NSDictionary. Then, having keys with values like {10,10,100,100} you can define the frame of you UI elements , using initwithframe you can create them and add as subviews.